# Writing variables with points?

Tags: matlab, variables, struct

I discovered today that I can write a variable in Matlab like this :

```
line2.start.cart = 1;
```

Is this a structure of line2, that has a subelement start?

Comment: See documentation here: [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) and [Create a Structure Array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In matlab the `.` operator allows you to create structs without explicit declaration, as in your case in which you are creating a struct with name `line2` which contains a struct `start` with attribute `cart`.

The `.` operator is also used to view the struct contents and extend existent structs.

[See also](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Arrays/Struct_Arrays)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
% create struct s
s.a=1;
s.b.c=2;
s.b.d=3;
% check class
class(s); % s is a struct
class(s.b); % also a struct
```

So s is a struct that contains another struct as an element. Also, check the documentation linked in the previous answer.